# How to store identification of div when id is already used?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyboard-shortcuts

So I am working on a keyboard forward- and back-script like they have on Tumblr and 9GAG (you can navigate the posts using your J and K keys).

My approach:

> User presses J (next) key
>
> Javascript uses JQuery Viewport to find out which "Jump"-ID is currently in:viewport
>
> Javascript adds +1 to the "Jump"-ID
>
> Javascript gets the position of the increased "Jump"-ID, scrolls there

Now the problem is the following:

```
<div class="content jump" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

I already defined the id of the div. So it looks like this:

```
<div class="content jump" id="1225">
<div class="content jump" id="1299">
<div class="content jump" id="1206">
<div class="content jump" id="1345">
```

However, in order to be able to jump in the right order I somehow need to store an additional identification, maybe like this...

```
<div class="content jump" id="1225" jump="1">
<div class="content jump" id="1299" jump="2">
<div class="content jump" id="1206" jump="3">
<div class="content jump" id="1345" jump="4">
```

That's just my imagination. There should be a way around this. If you have a better solution to the J / K problem, you are also free to tell me (maybe Tumblr or 9GAG has a much better one?)

Comment: Just add another class for the jump id?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `data-` attributes. For example:

```
<div class="content jump" id="1225" data-jump="1">
```

You can then fetch that data by using

```
$('#1225').data('jump');
```

Comment: How can I fetch that data in Javascript?

Comment: @JonasKaufmann It's still an attribute, you can fetch it by name or if you're using jQuery you can do as in the example above.

Comment: Hey, that's interesting. Is that a JQuery-specific thing, or a generally-supported bit of Javascript? And does it validate?

Comment: `data-` attributes are part of the HTML5 specification, and they do validate. :) They already have widespread support though, so don't be worried about the "HTML5" label. Also, in unsupporting browsers, this method will still work.

Comment: Alright! Follow-up question. Once I have fetched the data-jump integer, increased it by 1, how can I fetch the id of the div that has the new data-jump integer?

Comment: @JonasKaufmann - So you already know the data-jump integer? If so, you would use this: `var id = $("[data-jump='" + dataJump + "']").attr("id");`

Answer (score 0):

You can apply an arbitrary number of classes to a given object. So, simply changing the first tag to something like:

```
<div class="content jump jump-1" id="1225">
```

Should give you the hook you need. And it actually validates. :)

Comment: Just climbing on my soap box here.  People have vastly over-emphasized the speed advantage of id lookups.  On a modern browser the difference between $('#jump1') and $('.jump1') is about a factor of 2, and both take mere nanoseconds.